# Negative index coefficients of Laurent series for 1/sin(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity-theory

Given $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{\sin(z)}$

a) Give singularities

b) Determine coefficients $a_{-1}$ and $a_{-3}$ of the Laurent series

So I thought:

a) $n \pi$, where $n$ is an integer

b) $\dfrac{1}{\sin(z)}$ can be rewritten as $\dfrac{1}{z(1-1/6z^2+...)}$ so $a_1$ is $\dfrac{1}{6}$ but how can I find $a_{-1}$ and $a_{-3}$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: Coefficients... of what?  A power series?  A Laurent series?  A continued fraction?  I'm sure there is some context to make sense of mentions of $a_{-1},a_{-3}$, but you have not included enough of that context in your post.

Comment: @hardmath Laurent series

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin z\frac1{\sin z}=(z-\frac{z^3}6+\frac{z^5}{120}-...)(\frac1z+\frac16z+a_3z^3+...)=1$$

What is the coefficient of $z^4$?